How to search in a DCE-element with Faceted Search (ke_search) in TYPO3 12?
By default Faceted Search (ke_search) does not search DCE-elements in TYPO3 but I would like to enable this in ke_search.
In the DCE-element I mapped the field to tx_dce_index as described here:

The DCE-content is saved in the field

pi_flexform

in

tt_content

.
So I added this field to "tt_content fields which should be indexed" in the indexer of ke_search:

But still there is no result in the search for contents in the DCE-elements.
There is also the possibility to index content from additional pages as described here. But my content is already in tt_content as far as I see. The following code could work but I do not know what table to use and what should be the field:
[dce_further_reading]
table = ???
referenceFieldName = tt_content
fields[] = ???

Does anyone know on how to enable the search in DCE-elements?

You need to create an own Indexer that parse the pi_flexform.
You could take a peek at this indexer, this parse the pi_flexform:
https://github.com/MamounAlsmaiel/flux_kesearch_indexer
Its currently not V12 compatible but I think its a good start for creating an own one.
